# Defining solutions to FindRoot as a function of parameters in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, equation-solving

This works:

```
f[a_] := x /. FindRoot[x^2 - a == 0, {x, 1}]
f[3]
(* 1.73205 *)
```

I need this to work, but it doesn't:

```
y = x^2 - a == 0
g[a_] := x /. FindRoot[y == 0, {x, 1}]
g[3]
(* -a + x^2 == 0 *)
```

Instead, it produces the error messages

```
FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {1. -1. a==0.} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.}. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[y==0,{x,1}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
(* x /. FindRoot[y == 0, {x, 1}] *)
```

Why doesn't the second method work?  How can I get it to work for a large, far more complex problem with a long list of parameters on which the solution depends?

Comment: There is a Mathematica stack exchange. You posted this on math.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the Question, Mathematica does not equate the `a` in `y` with the argument of `g`.  This is a common issue.  Use this instead, so that `a` appears explicitly.

```
y[a_] = x^2 - a; g[a_] := x /. FindRoot[y[a] == 0, {x, 1}]
g[3]
(* 1.73205 *)
```