# Defining Solutions to FindRoot a functions of parameters-Part II

Tags: functions, equation-solving

Here's a similar question as the the [preceding question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72241/defining-solutions-to-findroot-as-a-function-of-parameters-in-mathematica) with the same title, but this time with vectors, which I need to use.  I followed the suggestion in the answer the the previous question, but it yields the same error.  I just don't understand why functions in Mathematica behave the way they do.

```
    aVec = {a[1], a[2]};  
    bVec = {b[1]};  
    y[aVec_, bVec_] = bVec[[1]]*x^2 - aVec[[1]] - aVec[[2]]  
    g[aVec_, bVec_] := x /. FindRoot[y[aVec, bVec] == 0, {x, 1}]

    g[{1, 2}, {1}]
```

> During evaluation of In[5]:= FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-1. a[1.]-1. a[2.]+1. b[1.]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.}. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[5]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[y[{1,2},{1}]==0,{x,1}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

```
(* x /. FindRoot[y[{1, 2}, {1}] == 0, {x, 1}] *)
```

Comment: Please use standard formatting, along the lines of my editing of your first question.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you do the formatting?  What are the commands?

Comment: Whenever you post a Question or an Answer, you will see a string of icons just above the box for typing. Hover over each to see its meaning, or click the ? at the right, followed by `advanced help`. The same is true for editing.  Also, be sure to read `Tour` under `help` at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
y[aVec_, bVec_] := bVec[[1]]*x^2 - aVec[[1]] - aVec[[2]]
g[aVec_, bVec_] := x /. FindRoot[y[aVec, bVec] == 0, {x, 1}]

g[{1, 2}, {1}]
```

> 1.73205

By using `Set` to define `y` instead of `SetDelayed` the function ignored the two parameters and used the already-defined `aVec` and `bVec`, which were non-numerical and led to the error.

That is, your definition evaluated to this:

```
y[_, _] = b[1]*x^2 - a[1] - a[2]
```